# How to customzie default grid dialog with Syncfusion in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, dialog, syncfusion

Hello I am using Blazor Server .Net 6.0 and I was wondering if you can just edit the default dialog from SfGrid somehow.

[default dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7JH4.png)

I almost did it by just creating my own dialog, but somehow I didn't get anywhere. The only real problem I have with the default dialog is that the IsModal only applies for the 2nd Grid not the entire site. I hope someone can help me customizing the default grid dialog.

Here my progress:

[C# Code in Blazor using Syncfusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfA7e.jpg)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I Already Trimmed it. The Code is not really part of my question it was just to show that I was trying something different. I just want to know if it is possible to customize the default grid dialog and if someone could show me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a button in a custom dialog and utilize the FooterTemplate, you can render the button to meet your requirements. Refer to the below code snippet.

```
<SfDialog @ref="Dialog" Width="250px" Visible="false" ShowCloseIcon="true" IsModal="true">
<DialogTemplates>

    @*Here you can customize the Header and Content of cancel confirmation dialog*@

    <Header> Cancel Changes</Header>

    <Content> You  want to cancel the record changes</Content>

    <FooterTemplate>

        <SfButton OnClick="@OkClick" Content="Yes" IsPrimary="true"></SfButton>

        <SfButton OnClick="@CancelClick" Content="No"></SfButton>

    </FooterTemplate>
```

Regarding the update and cancel buttons, it enables changes to be updated in the grid. These buttons remain enabled until the changes are either canceled or updated in the grid. this behavior is the default for the grid. So tried to replicate the problem but wasn't able to. Please refer to the sample below. If you are still experiencing the issue, please provide a reproducible sample.

Sample Link: https://blazorplayground.syncfusion.com/embed/hDrANuBFVNyrrcWK?appbar=true&editor=true&result=true&errorlist=true&theme=bootstrap5

Additionally, if you want to enable or disable buttons in any other scenario, you can use the EnableToolbarItemsAsync() public method of grid to achieve your requirement.
https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/blazor/Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SfGrid-1.html#Syncfusion_Blazor_Grids_SfGrid_1_EnableToolbarItemsAsync_System_Collections_Generic_List_System_String__System_Boolean_

Answer (score 0):

You want to display a custom cancel dialog when canceling the edit changes. To achieve this, set the 'ShowConfirmDialog' property to false in the 'EditSettings' component.. This will prevent the built-in cancel dialog from rendering, allowing you to use your customized dialog instead. Please refer to the code snippet and sample below.

```
<SfGrid @ref="Grid" TValue="Order" DataSource="@Orders" AllowPaging="true" Toolbar="@(new List<string>() { "Add", "Delete", "Update", "Cancel" })" Height="315">

<GridEditSettings AllowAdding="true" AllowEditing="true" AllowDeleting="true" Mode="EditMode.Batch" ShowConfirmDialog="false"></GridEditSettings>

<GridEvents  OnToolbarClick="ToolbarClickHandler" TValue="Order"></GridEvents>
```

Reference: https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/blazor/Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.GridEditSettings.html#Syncfusion_Blazor_Grids_GridEditSettings_ShowConfirmDialog

Sample Link: https://blazorplayground.syncfusion.com/embed/hjhqZahcrJjngzfi?appbar=true&editor=true&result=true&errorlist=true&theme=bootstrap5

Comment: Thank you very much for that information. How do I implement my "Yes" and "No" Button in my custom dialog. I tried it with my methodes OkClick() and CancelClick() but I have no clue how to, for example activate the Cancel and Update Buttons from the Toolbar (which get disabled after clicking on Cancel) after clicken on "No" ( "Nein" in my Code). Im still looking for a solution with the default grid syncfusion dialog.